# Makefile include directive failing for long path Windows 10

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, long-path

I have a Makefile that includes another makefile with the include makefile directive and the included Makefile exists on a deep path (200 characters). The Makefile doesn't produce any error on reading the long path Makefile however it's contents are not included in the main Makefile.
`include <long-path>/my.mk`
I have tried using UNC path post script as well but that also seems to have no effect. Any help how to handle long paths inclusions in Makefiles?

Comment: You can try to use extended path format `\\?\C:\path\to\somewhere` or opt-in for an unlimited path length. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation.

Comment: \\?\ Doesn't work with Makefile and it produce no differences.

Answer (score 0):

There can be different ways on how you handle this:

1. Provide Relative Path: A relative path refers to a location that is relative to a current directory, so you dont require to give a full path
2. Keep your files/sandbox at very short location if possible: Eg: `C:`
3. You can use `mount`/ `shortpath` option to use short paths.